# SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER is not paired with SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT

Tags: debug-logs

I have a debug log where some SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER are logged with value `true` but corresponding SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT are not logged. Have you come across this issue? Any reason why it is so?

Here is the debug log.

```
38.0 APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,FINER;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
17:24:15.0 (77769)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|00563000001BPzQ|<replaced>|Pacific Standard Time|GMT-07:00
17:24:15.0 (127624)|EXECUTION_STARTED
17:24:15.0 (133556)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|06663000000ANX5|VF: /apex/<replaced>
17:24:15.0 (291734)|VF_DESERIALIZE_VIEWSTATE_BEGIN|06663000000ANX5
17:24:15.0 (3904968)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[72]|Bytes:3
17:24:15.0 (3965545)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[77]|Bytes:152
17:24:15.0 (3986620)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[342]|Bytes:408
17:24:15.0 (4004365)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[355]|Bytes:408
17:24:15.0 (4021900)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[467]|Bytes:48
17:24:15.0 (4057049)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[139]|Bytes:6
17:24:15.0 (7595571)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[10]|<replaced>|String|false|true
17:24:15.0 (9529752)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[17]|<replaced>|String|false|true
17:24:15.0 (10697332)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[13]|<replaced>|String|false|true
17:24:15.0 (11501823)|VF_DESERIALIZE_VIEWSTATE_END
17:24:15.0 (17475340)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
17:24:15.0 (17524351)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:196
17:24:15.0 (17535268)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:21
17:24:15.0 (17540809)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
17:24:15.0 (17553219)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|01p63000000O44Q|<replaced>
17:24:15.0 (17563738)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
17:24:15.0 (17570548)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
17:24:15.0 (17577479)|METHOD_EXIT|[1]|<replaced>
17:24:15.0 (18360196)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:20
17:24:15.0 (18374016)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[34]|this|<replaced>|true|false
17:24:15.0 (18460266)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[34]
17:24:15.0 (18462771)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[35]
17:24:15.0 (18501345)|METHOD_ENTRY|[35]|01p63000000O44Q|<replaced>
17:24:15.0 (18524796)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[38]|this|<replaced>|true|false
17:24:15.0 (18567741)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[38]
17:24:15.0 (18569745)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[39]
17:24:15.0 (18648316)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[32]|Bytes:4
17:24:15.0 (18677524)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[40]
17:24:15.0 (18687624)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[40]|Bytes:20
17:24:15.0 (19850989)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[40]|Bytes:40
17:24:15.0 (19873760)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[40]|apexJobCS|<replaced>|true|false
17:24:15.0 (19986804)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[50]|Bytes:5
17:24:15.0 (20013364)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[56]|Bytes:5
17:24:15.0 (20027192)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[64]|Bytes:7
17:24:15.0 (20050148)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[62]
17:24:15.0 (20052526)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[63]
17:24:15.0 (20063551)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[63]|Bytes:22
17:24:15.0 (20157849)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[64]
17:24:15.0 (20221280)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[32]|Bytes:4
17:24:15.0 (20244421)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[66]
17:24:15.0 (20253869)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[66]|Bytes:18
17:24:15.0 (20358367)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[66]|Bytes:3
17:24:15.0 (20386489)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[66]|Bytes:21
17:24:15.0 (20432207)|METHOD_EXIT|[35]|01p63000000O44Q|<replaced>
17:24:15.0 (36630599)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
17:24:15.0 (36664612)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:356
17:24:15.0 (36676287)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:78
17:24:15.0 (36682160)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:31
17:24:15.0 (36687288)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:3
17:24:15.0 (36710900)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|01p630000013Sl6|<replaced>
17:24:15.0 (36717317)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
17:24:15.0 (36721639)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
17:24:15.0 (36726032)|METHOD_EXIT|[1]|<replaced>
17:24:15.0 (37276873)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
17:24:15.0 (37308737)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:78
17:24:15.0 (37319613)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:412
17:24:15.0 (37325177)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:46
17:24:15.0 (37330483)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:6
17:24:15.0 (37336095)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:3
17:24:15.0 (37361602)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|01p630000013KkA|<replaced>
17:24:15.0 (37368240)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
17:24:15.0 (37371825)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
17:24:15.0 (37373621)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[286]
17:24:15.0 (37375454)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[291]
17:24:15.0 (37376941)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[298]
17:24:15.0 (37378337)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[303]
17:24:15.0 (37380042)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[310]
17:24:15.0 (37384324)|METHOD_EXIT|[1]|<replaced>
17:24:15.0 (37439602)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:140
17:24:15.0 (37449806)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:11
17:24:15.0 (38091446)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
17:24:15.0 (38710558)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
17:24:15.0 (38791825)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
17:24:15.0 (41898148)|VF_SERIALIZE_VIEWSTATE_BEGIN|06663000000ANX5
17:24:15.0 (45737385)|VF_SERIALIZE_VIEWSTATE_END
17:24:15.49 (49635035)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
17:24:15.49 (49635035)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

17:24:15.49 (49635035)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

17:24:15.0 (49680059)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|VF: /apex/<replaced>
17:24:15.0 (50783097)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

Comment: I am not sure that it should be paired "Exit" also..however, I couldn't find a document that confirms this.

Comment: Based on what is logged, looks like it is not paired. But naming is really confusing and so is documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that it shouldn't be paired "Exit"..however, I couldn't find a document that confirms this.

I think, whenever it goes to new class or execution phase, it states whether it's running in system mode or not.

Comment: If so, what is SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT is for?